# Windows 10 USB not being detected, and diskpart showing USB as unusable

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, partition-recovery

I am using Windows and I used a USB to boot a Linux .iso, to test it. I cleaned the USB after use, via diskpart, created a primary partition and I made a quick format using Windows Explorer. Now, however, something is off. The USB is completely unrecognized, Windows Explorer spits out a variety of error messages when I select the USB, including:

**The media may have been changed**; **There was an I/O error**; **The directory name F:  is invalid.**

Looking at the Properties menu in File Explorer shows that there is 0 free space on the USB and 0 used. Also, Windows can't seem to format it.

This is what diskpart says:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pOFl.png)

Diskpart allows me to select the disk, although it isn't listed; it doesn't allow me to "clean" the disk, but when I try to create a new primary partition, it outputs error messages like "cannot access the volume", "the media in the drive may have been changed", "paramters are incorrect" etc.
Also,
Disk Management shows that there are no partitions on the USB, and changing the drive letter doesn't do much.

Edit: Diskpart doesn't allow me to clean the USB.

If the USB is corrupted or there are bad sectors, or whatnot, what can be a potential solution?

Answer (score 1):

First see this website: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-unformattable-usb-drive/

Skip points 3 and 4. Just after cleaning, you should be able to make a partitions on usb stick using diskpart.

The guide for you:

Your USB drive isn't ruined; it simply needs a new primary partition. This can easily be fixed in DISKPART using the CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY command.

From DISKPART (Run with Administrator Priveleges)

1. Type LIST DISK and hit ENTER
2. Find the usb disk number in the menu (identifiable by it's size), then type SELECT DISK (corresponding number) and hit ENTER
3. From here, type CLEAN, then hit ENTER
4. At this point you should convert your disk to whichever partition format you desire (MBR for older "legacy" BIOS setups or GPT for newer UEFI-boot operating systems, respectively) by entering CONVERT (GPT or MBR)
5. Then type CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY, and hit ENTER
6. Type EXIT,

Windows Explorer should now recognize your filesystem, and you'll be able to format the disk successfully without any error messages.

Then try to install the balena etcher in Windows from this website https://www.balena.io/etcher/ and make a bootable usb via this software. Hope this will solve the issue.

Let me know did it solve the problem, or not.

Comment: Like I said, it's not allowing me to create a new partition. It says that the parameter is incorrect. As I also said, diskpart doesn't even list the USB drive. Although Windows Explorer weirdly says that the device is working properly - also, diskpart doesn't allow me to clean the USB. Diskmgmt also says that the USB is "online", but it has no partition- no free space either. I can't even create a new partition.

Comment: Can you prepare another bootable usb stick with some Linux live and format this faulty usb stick under Linux live using fdisk?

Comment: That's the problem, let me give it a shot.